# python script to assign id based on dataframe fields

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to write an iterative script in python that would see assign an id to a customer based on whether they've met conditions in my lookup table. Normally, I would accomplish this with a sql join, but I need a procedural script that would see whether they've met the conditions that exist in the lookup, then assign them that id. Some attributes are not required or available, so a sql join would not work, since the join would require that all conditions be met. See the example, below:

customers table

```
customer attr1 attr2 attr3
jerry    a     r     g
tom      q     e     h
cindy    c     f     j
```

id_lookup table

```
id attr1   attr2   attr3
1  a       (null)  g
2  (null)  e       h
3  c       f       (null)
```

final output

```
customer  id
jerry     1
tom       2
cindy     3
```

Note that jerry had a match on attr1 and attr3, so met the conditions, thus was assigned 1. The script moves on to the next customer to assign an id procedurally, starting at 1 and moving on in ascending order.

in sql, I would write

```
select a.customer
   , b.id
from customers a
join id_lookup b 
   on ( a.attr1 = b.attr1
   and a.attr2 = b.attr2
   and a.attr3 = b.attr2 )
```

However, some attributes are not available and since a customer might match many ids, may not be assigned the right once, since the customer should be assigned the id with the lowest value that they qualify for.

Is there a script in python that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in SQL.

```
select a.name
     , min(b.id)
from customers a
join id_lookup b 
    on ( (a.attr1 = b.attr1 or b.attr1 is null)
    and (a.attr2 = b.attr2 or b.attr2 is null)
    and (a.attr3= b.attr3 or b.attr3 is null) )
group by a.name;
```

I'm sure you could also solve the problem in Python, but that would either require writing the equivalent in an ORM (and hence any solution would depend on what ORM you are using) or loading the entire tables into Python and processing them there, which would be impractical if your tables were of significant size.

Comment: Thank you so much, David. Yeah, my tables are like 50GB @ 170M rows. This is perfect. So glad I can solve it in SQL. Again, Thanks!